# Dirichlet condition from user-defined polygon

Tags: finite-element-method, boundary-conditions, polygons, polyhedra

I would like to specify a Dirichlet condition from a polyhedron defined by a set of points.

```
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 5, Region`RegionProperty[RegionBoundary[object], {x, y, z}, "FastDescription"][[1]][[2]]]
```

However, this part

```
    Region`RegionProperty[RegionBoundary[object], {x, y, z}, 
    "FastDescription"][[1]][[2]]]
```

doesn't work given the oddly shaped polygon given by `RegionBoundary[object]`. I haven't been able to find out much about `RegionProperty` or find out where I can find alternatives to `"FastDescription"`.

Here is how I define `object`:

```
center = {39, 19, 0};
objcoords = {{0.35744634112855245, 
19.49760834744405}, {10.42305798361631, 
19.4864491327628}, {12.243503729806417, 
18.29241316186902}, {16.364505056976796, 
18.11755617591872}, {18.196197885680288, 
22.372731682760513}, {15.189009198663676, 
24.589812823211748}, {0.2100041188046311, 24.861851631504276}, {0,
 24.86}, {-61.5, 24.86}, {-61.5, 15.86}, {-5, 15.86}};
objcoords[[;; , 1]] = objcoords[[;; , 1]] - center[[1]];
objcoords[[;; , 2]] = objcoords[[;; , 2]] - center[[2]];
(*create 3D polygon from the coordinates*)
objTop = 
  Table[{objcoords[[i, 1]], objcoords[[i, 2]], 1}, {i, 1, 
    Length[objcoords]}];
objBottom = 
  Table[{objcoords[[i, 1]], objcoords[[i, 2]], -1}, {i, 1, 
    Length[objcoords]}];
object = ConvexHullRegion[Join[objTop, objBottom]]
```

Please could someone help me get a Dirichlet condition from a user-defined polyhedron/polygon?

Thank you in advance for any help you might be able to give me with this.

[image: object polygon]

Comment: It is not clear what do you try to solve. Is `object` to be a region for your  numerical solution?

Comment: Thanks for your question. object is an electrode in a wider space in which I need to find the potential due to the electrode being near by. That is why I need to set a boundary condition on object.

Comment: What is the region (wider space?) to solve this problem? Could you upload equation and boundary condition in mathematical notation?

Comment: bc = {
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == Vobj, 
    Region`RegionProperty[RegionBoundary[object], {x, y, z}, 
       "FastDescription"][[1]][[2]]]
   };

Comment: eq = Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0; 
U = NDSolveValue[{eq, bc}, u, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh];

Comment: Here is the wider region:
xair = yair = zair = 70;
air = Cuboid[{-xair, -yair, -zair}, {xair, yair, zair}]; reg = 
 RegionDifference[air, object];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, 
   MeshRefinementFunction -> 
    Function[{vertices, area}, 
     area > 0.1 (0.1 + 10 Norm[Mean[vertices]])]];

Comment: It looks like `object` length on `x` from about -100. to -21, while `air` starts from -70. Is it correct?

Comment: That's true, we can make air bigger, I've played around with a range of sizes. I'm not sure that's what is causing the difficulty here with the unusual shape though. I think the difficulty is to do with the odd shape...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solution with zero boundary condition on the air boundary

```
center = {39, 19, 0};
objcoords = {{0.35744634112855245, 
    19.49760834744405}, {10.42305798361631, 
    19.4864491327628}, {12.243503729806417, 
    18.29241316186902}, {16.364505056976796, 
    18.11755617591872}, {18.196197885680288, 
    22.372731682760513}, {15.189009198663676, 
    24.589812823211748}, {0.2100041188046311, 24.861851631504276}, {0,
     24.86}, {-61.5, 24.86}, {-61.5, 15.86}, {-5, 15.86}};
objcoords[[;; , 1]] = objcoords[[;; , 1]] - center[[1]];
objcoords[[;; , 2]] = objcoords[[;; , 2]] - center[[2]];
(*create 3D polygon from the coordinates*)
objTop = Table[{objcoords[[i, 1]], objcoords[[i, 2]], 1}, {i, 1, 
    Length[objcoords]}];
objBottom = 
  Table[{objcoords[[i, 1]], objcoords[[i, 2]], -1}, {i, 1, 
    Length[objcoords]}];
object = ConvexHullRegion[Join[objTop, objBottom]]

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

xair = yair = zair = 70; air = 
 Cuboid[{-xair, -yair, -zair}, {xair, yair, zair}]; reg = 
 RegionDifference[air, object]; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[reg, 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> 
   Function[{vertices, area}, 
    area > 0.1 (0.1 + 10 Norm[Mean[vertices]])]];
xmax = Max[objcoords[[All, 1]]]; ymm = MinMax[objcoords[[All, 2]]]

bc = {DirichletCondition[
   u[x, y, z] == 5, -xair <= x <= xmax && -1 <= z <= 1 && 
    ymm[[1]] <= y <= ymm[[2]]], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, True]}; eq = 
 Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0; U = 
 NDSolveValue[{eq, bc}, u, Element[{x, y, z}, mesh]]
```

Visualization

```
{ContourPlot[U[x, y, 0], {x, -xair, xair}, {y, -yair, yair}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 20, FrameLabel -> Automatic], 
 ContourPlot[U[x, 0, z], {x, -xair, xair}, {z, -zair, zair}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 20, FrameLabel -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: This is it! Thank you so very much!!

Comment: So it looks like the exact locations of the edges of the object don't matter so much in the Dirichlet condition then? For example, x < xmax suffices

Comment: Yes,  with `DirichletCondition[
   u[x, y, z] == 5, -xair <= x <= xmax && -1 <= z <= 1 && 
    ymm[[1]] <= y <= ymm[[2]]]` Mathematica FEM automatically computed  all cells on the surface of `object` included in the `mesh`.

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: @ECrane You are welcome!